# jackson-databind throws NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper even though its in shaded jar

Tags: java, gradle, jackson-databind, spongeapi

I'm attempting to run a sponge plugin with an external dependency (JDA) and when i build a shaded jar with the dependency it still says that jackson-databind isnt found even though when i open the jar itself i can see the class it cant find.

I've tried including JDA as a local jar, i've tried including jackson itself as a dependency, I even tried taking out JDA and just including jackson and it still couldnt find it. For some reason it looks like jackson doesn't like to be included in shaded jars

```
plugins {
    id 'org.spongepowered.plugin' version '0.9.0'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "5.1.0"
}

group = pluginGroup
version = pluginVersion

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.spongepowered:spongeapi:7.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'org.spongepowered:spongeapi:7.1.0'
    compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:4.0.0_52'

}

sponge.plugin.id = pluginId
```

I have to imagine this has something to do with it being a plugin and not a standalone jar and that somehow effects the classpath or something, at this point i'm not sure what's going on. Whenever i start the server with the shaded jar and it tries to use JDA it throws this error:

```
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]: Exception in thread "OkHttp Dispatcher" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at net.dv8tion.jda.api.utils.data.DataObject.<clinit>(DataObject.java:54)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Response.parseBody(Response.java:204)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Response.parseBody(Response.java:182)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Response.get(Response.java:124)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Response.getObject(Response.java:105)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at net.dv8tion.jda.api.utils.SessionControllerAdapter.lambda$getGateway$0(SessionControllerAdapter.java:85)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.RestActionImpl.handleSuccess(RestActionImpl.java:247)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.RestActionImpl.handleResponse(RestActionImpl.java:237)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.Request.handleResponse(Request.java:197)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.Requester.lambda$attemptRequest$1(Requester.java:191)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.FunctionalCallback.onResponse(FunctionalCallback.java:60)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:216)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:101)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[22:08:55 ERROR] [STDERR]:  ... 16 more
```